# Django: validation fails for many-to-many field with empty QueryDict as initial data

Tags: python, django

**Setup:**

- Python 3.5.1 with Django 1.9.
- I have a class-based generic view `CreateRentView` operating on the model `Rent`. I implemented a custom `ModelForm` `RentForm` to implement additional validations (e.g., ensure `start_time <= end_time`).
- When creating a new `Rent` (via `CreateRentView`), first user defines start and end time. This triggers an AJAX request to get the available objects for this time frame and fills the `rental_objects` HTML widget using Javascript (see screenshot below).

**Problem:**

- Everything is working fine (custom validation and AJAX communication), but when submitting the form I get a validation error for (many-to-many) field `rental_objects`: `Select a valid choice. 1 is not one of the available choices.`
- Note: in the screenshot below, rental object `MB1` was selected before submitting the form.

This is caused because I want to initialize the field `rental_objects` empty. Therefore, method `get_form()` of class `CreateRentView` sets form field `rental_objects` to an empty `QuerySet`:

```
def get_form(self):
    form = super(generic.CreateView, self).get_form()
    # Rental objects are retrieved via AJAX after start and end time is defined.
    form.fields["rental_objects"].queryset = RentalObject.objects.none()
```

Obviously this triggers an internal Django validation that ensures that this field is submitted empty.

How can I avoid this validation?

PS: Of course, I could not override `get_form()` and empty the HTML widget for `rental_objects` using Javascript. But, this would be just a messy workaround

Django-AJAX-ManyToManyField:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is from your rental objects' choices.

If you use integers for your choices you should use IntegerField. For CharField use strings

Comment: `rental_objects` are modeled as many-to-many field in model `Rent`:

    class Rent(models.Model):
        rental_objects = models.ManyToManyField(RentalObject, ...)

If I don't override `RentCreateView`'s `get_form() method following HTML code is rendered:
    <select multiple="multiple" id="id_rental_objects" name="rental_objects">
        <option value="1">MB1</option>
        <option value="2">CB1</option>
        ....

The same is rendered after AJAX request.

Comment: Can you try the form without ajax and share your models if still doesn't work?

Comment: The form works without using AJAX but it also works with AJAX (if `get_form()` is not overriden; i.e., providing default `QuerySet` for model `RentalObject`). The models can be found on [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/61627740389b8704a777).